# Blank Tk window showing with no attributes

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

My code so far is very basic so when I ran it the first time it worked perfectly fine, however, once I added two functions for each button command, rather than display the title and widgets, nothing is shown and instead it is simply a blank screen with the title "Tk". It was working fine before and when I tried to then remove the functions, it still had the same issue.

```
import sqlite3
import sys
import os
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk
import uuid
screen = Tk()

class Main:

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self._frame = None
        self.loginscreen = StringVar()
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.var_FName = StringVar()
        self.var_SName = StringVar()
        self.var_password1 = StringVar()
        self.var_usertype = StringVar()
        self.UserID = StringVar()

    def Mainmenu(self):
        screen.geometry("300x250")
        screen.title("Manager of stuff")
        Label(screen, text = "Login Menu", bg = "light blue", width = "300", font = ('',35),pady = 10).pack()
        Label(text = "").pack()
        Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = self.login).pack()
        Label(text = "").pack()
        Button(text = "Register",height = "2", width = "30", command = self.register).pack()

    def login(self):

        login = Toplevel(screen)
        login.title("Login")
        login.geometry("500x450")

        Label(login, text = "Please enter your username and password below: ").pack()
        Label(login, text = "").pack()
        Label(login, text = "Username: ").pack()
        Entry(login, textvariable = username).pack()
        Label(login, text = "").pack()
        Label(login, text = "Password: ").pack()
        Entry(login, textvariable = password, show= "*").pack()
        Label(login, text = "").pack()
        Button(login, text = "Login As a Teacher", width = 20, height = 3, command = self.TeachLoginFunc).pack()
        Label(login, text = "").pack()
        Button(login, text = "Login As a Student", width = 20, height = 3, command = self.Main.StudLoginFunc).pack()
        Label(login, text = "").pack()
        Button(login, text = "Back", width = 30, height = 4, command = self.logindestroy).pack()
        login.mainloop()

    def register(self):

        regscreen = Toplevel(screen)
        regscreen.title("Registration")
        regscreen.geometry("500x500")

        Label(regscreen, text = "Please enter your username and password below: ").pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "Firstname: ").pack()
        Entry(regscreen, textvariable = var_FName).pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "Surname: ").pack()
        Entry(regscreen, textvariable = var_SName).pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "Password: ").pack()
        Entry(regscreen, textvariable = var_password1).pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Button(regscreen, text = "Teacher", width = 10, height = 1, command = self.teachregfunc).pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Button(regscreen, text = "Student", width = 10, height = 1, command = self.studregfunc).pack()
        Label(regscreen, text = "").pack()
        Button(regscreen, text = "Back", width = 30, height = 4, command = self.regscreendestroy).pack()
        regscreen.mainloop()    

Main(screen)

screen.mainloop()
```

Is it just my tkinter that has somehow broken or something, or is the code broken somewhere somehow?

Comment: At least one problem is the multiple calls to `mainloop`. You need to call that exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told python what function you want to run.

try:

```
Main(screen).Mainmenu()
```

instead of:

```
Main(screen)
```